# increment localStorage object name to store data from inputs

Tags: javascript, loops, input, local-storage

**This is for testing purposes only.**

i'm trying to store data from 3 inputs (types: text,number) and store them in localStorage. which continuously increment every submit.

i seem to be overwriting value0, value1, value2 on the second submission instead of further incrementing to value3, value4, value5.

expected result:

1. first submit value0,value1,value2
2. second submit value3,value4,value5
3. third submit value6,value7,value8
   etc.

JS:

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', createEntry());

function createEntry(){
    const inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        let value = inputs[i].value; 

        localStorage.setItem(`value${i}`, JSON.stringify(value));

    }  
};
```

gather all input by grabbing all input tags, loop through found elements. assign new statement to looped values and store them in localStorage. increment the item name to avoid overwriting the previously looped item.

HTML:

```
<div class="form">
      <input type="text" required>
      <input type="text" required>
      <input type="number" min="1" max="120" required>
      <button type="button" id="btn">Add</button>
</div>
```

Comment: hi @Plague3D can you provide proper explanation and add HTML code as well

Comment: @GaganV done to the best of my ability, I'm unsure how i can clarify my question further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you coded it will override the saved values because `i` always gets reset to 0 when the function runs. There are many different ways to re-write your code, one being the below:

**Store the last index used**

```
// By the way, there was an error in this line, you were calling createEntry()
// instead of passing the function as a callback.
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', createEntry);

function createEntry() {
    const inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

    let i;
    let index = getNextIndex();

    for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        let value = inputs[i].value; 
        localStorage.setItem(`value${index}`, JSON.stringify(value));
        index++;
    }

    localStorage.setItem('nextIndex', index);
}

function getNextIndex() {
    const index = localStorage.getItem('nextIndex');
    return index ? parseInt(index) : 0;
}
```